# Lazy Loading not working properly

Tags: java, android, image, android-recyclerview, lazy-loading

I am showing a list of contacts in a recyclerview. I am showing contact profile images, first I am loading these images from server and then storing these images in an external memory.

Then Loading the images from external storage. I can see the images loaded, but as I scroll I can see some images for a second or two then they get disappear and I can see the default image icon.

```
public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ContactHolder> {


    private List<Contact> contactList;
    File myDir1;
    private Activity mContext;

    private Boolean fileExists;
    private File file;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL= 20;

    public ContactAdapter(Activity context, List<Contact> contactList) {
        this.contactList = contactList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ContactHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,null);
        ContactHolder mh = new ContactHolder(v);

        return mh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ContactHolder contactHolder, int i) {

        final Contact contact = contactList.get(i);
        //  Log.e("Imagename",""+"http://xesoftwares.co.in/contactsapi/profile_images/85368a5bbd6cffba8a3aa202a80563a2.jpg");//+feedItem.getThumbnail());

        Target target = new Target() {

            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

                // your code here ...

                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,(int)(bitmap.getWidth()*0.8), (int)(bitmap.getHeight()*0.8), true);

                contactHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                Log.e("ProfileImage", contact.getmProfileImage());

                SaveImages(bitmap, contact.getmProfileImage());

            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                contactHolder.thumbnail.setImageDrawable(errorDrawable);
                // do error handling as required
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                contactHolder.thumbnail.setImageDrawable(placeHolderDrawable);
            }
        };

        contactHolder.thumbnail.setTag(target);

        String url = ServiceUrl.getBaseUrl() + ServiceUrl.getImageUserUrl() + contact.getmProfileImage();

        Log.e("url",url);

        if(contact.getmProfileImage().equals(""))

        {

            file = new File("");

            fileExists = file.exists();

            contactHolder.thumbnail.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_48dp));
        }
        else {

            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ContactProfileImages/" + contact.getmProfileImage());

            fileExists = file.exists();
        }

        if(fileExists)
        {

            Log.e("fileExists",file.getAbsolutePath());

            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath(), bmOptions);

            contactHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }

        else {

            Log.e("Picasso",file.getAbsolutePath());

            Picasso.with(mContext).load(url)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_24dp)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_24dp)
                    .into(target);
        }

        contactHolder.title.setText(contact.getmUserName());
        //feedListRowHolder.genre.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getGenre()));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != contactList ? contactList.size() : 0);
    }

    public void SaveImages(Bitmap bitmap,String profileName)
    {

        try {
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            File myDir = new File(root +"/ContactProfileImages");

            if (!myDir.exists()) {
                myDir.mkdirs();
            }

            // String name = new Date().toString();=
            String name = profileName;
            File myDir1 = new File(myDir, name);
            if(!myDir1.exists()) {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myDir1);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,out);

                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }


        } catch(Exception e){
            // some action
        }

        //myDir1= imageFilePath1.getprofile();

    }


    public class ContactHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        protected CircleImageView thumbnail;
        protected TextView title;

        public ContactHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.thumbnail = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Contact contact = contactList.get(getAdapterPosition());

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
            final Window window = dialog.getWindow();

            WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp =window.getAttributes();
            wlp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.TOP;
            wlp.y=320;
            window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            window.setAttributes(wlp);

            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
            TextView txtusername = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtusername);
            TextView txtmobile = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtmobile);
            TextView txtemail = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtemail);

            txtusername.setText(contact.getmUserName());
            txtemail.setText(contact.getmEmailId());
            txtmobile.setText(contact.getmMobileNo());

            SquareImageView image = (SquareImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
            ImageView image1 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image1);
            ImageView image2 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image2);
            ImageView image3 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image3);

            if(contact.getmProfileImage().equals(""))

            {
                image.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.profile_icon));
            }
            else {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ContactProfileImages/" + contact.getmProfileImage());
                BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath(), bmOptions);

                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

            image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp);
            image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_textsms_black_24dp);
            image3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_email_black_24dp);

            image2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Uri sms_uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + contact.getmMobileNo());
                    Intent sms_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, sms_uri);
                    mContext.startActivity(sms_intent);
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

            image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + contact.getmMobileNo()));
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            image3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{contact.getmEmailId()});
                    email.setType("message/rfc822");
                    mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));

                }
            });

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
            // if button is clicked, view all information custom dialog

            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    ((MainActivity)mContext).finish();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,DetailViewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("contact",contact);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);

                    dialog.dismiss();


                }
            });
            dialog.show();

        }
    }
 }
```

EDIT : I searched for the same issue with picasso library, when we load images from server, for this I got the solution from SO as :

```
   recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
    recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    recyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
```

And this worked when I am loading the images from server, but when I am loading the images from the external storage still the problem exists.

Can anyone help with this please? Thank you..

Comment: it maybe unrelated but have a look at this [git link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView#implementing-with-recyclerview) , instead of `.post` use `.postDelayed`

Comment: where to use .postDelayed?? @Mr.Z

Comment: @Sid: Check the code at  http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112

Comment: you are not using Picasso which is made for, yes Picasso not just download image for you it store that image in cache for offline use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then Loading the images from external storage. I can see the images
>   loaded, but as I scroll I can see some images for a second or two then
>   they get disappear and I can see the default image icon.

This is becuase you are using Target callback in picasso. And callbacks are called little bit late when you are scrolling the list. Just remove the target and use the imageview into Picasso, it should work fine. Also you don't need to cache bitmaps on your own as Picasso does it for you.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ContactHolder contactHolder, int i) {
    final Contact contact = contactList.get(i);
    //  Log.e("Imagename",""+"http://xesoftwares.co.in/contactsapi/profile_images/85368a5bbd6cffba8a3aa202a80563a2.jpg");//+feedItem.getThumbnail());

    String url = ServiceUrl.getBaseUrl() + ServiceUrl.getImageUserUrl() + contact.getmProfileImage();
    Log.e("url",url);

    if(contact.getmProfileImage().equals("")) {
        file = new File("");
        fileExists = file.exists();
        contactHolder.thumbnail.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_48dp));
    } else {
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ContactProfileImages/" + contact.getmProfileImage());
        fileExists = file.exists();
    }

    Log.e("Picasso",file.getAbsolutePath());

    Picasso.with(mContext).load(url)
        .error(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_24dp)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_24dp)
        .into(contactHolder.thumbnail);

    contactHolder.title.setText(contact.getmUserName());
    //feedListRowHolder.genre.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getGenre()));
}
```

Comment: but I need to get the location of the stored image to show image in another activity and I found that we can't get the path of cache image stored by picasso , so I followed this way to save images in external storage and use it.

Comment: you don't need location to show same image in another activity, u just need image url. Picasso stores the image with image url as the key. So when you need image in some other activity or fragment it can be restored from cache if its already stored

Answer (score 1):

use this code in your Application class to apply setting in whole app.

```
final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
// Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(getApplicationContext());
builder.memoryCache(new LruCache(cacheSize));
Picasso built = builder.build();
built.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);// it will show indicator where it downloaded from
built.setLoggingEnabled(false);
Picasso.setSingletonInstance(built);
```

now pass the url to Picasso  to load it to view .If you are dealing with large image you can resize image size also for faster loading.

```
Picasso
    .with(mContext)
    .load(url)
    .error(R.drawable.on_error)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder)
    //.resize(custom_width,custom_height)  put custom_height to 0 if you want to maintain aspect ratio
    .into(your_view);
```

Comment: I want to load images from external memory, can I load it using picasso?@NANDAN KUMAR SINGH

Comment: yes!!, you can load from external memory by passing image uri.

Comment: can you please show me an example? @NANDAN KUMAR SINGH

Comment: http://square.github.io/picasso/ follow this url for complete example, it will help you

Comment: but I need to get the location of the stored image to show image in another activity and I found that we can't get the path of cache image stored by picasso , so I followed this way to save images in external storage and use it. @NANDAN KUMAR SINGH 1

Comment: practically speaking, in Picasso context, you don't need to worry about this. If you have downloaded any image in your app using Picasso your image will be available in offline until the cache size get full. it means your image will be in your device in any activity

Answer (score 0):

I may mistake, but your problem could be caused by that you use `Contact` that you got from your dataset by **layout position**, but since you use it asynchroniously in `onBitmapLoaded` callback, the position could already be changed at that moment. So all you need is to use **adapter position** as follows:

```
@Override
public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

     // your code here ...

    Contact c = contactList.get(contactHolder.getAdapterPosition());

    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,(int)(bitmap.getWidth()*0.8), (int)(bitmap.getHeight()*0.8), true);

    contactHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    Log.e("ProfileImage", c.getmProfileImage());

    SaveImages(bitmap, c.getmProfileImage());
}
```

I'm not sure that it would be helpful, but let's try, and I hope it will be:)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna simply load the image then why you need to store in the external storage.if you have to store for any other purpose then store it but when you show it in the ImageView then please use any third party api like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) it does lazy loading and also it does all type of cache memory management also provies many display fasality.

Hope this will help you

Comment: I am saving the images in folder because if user is offline still he should see the list. So I want to load the images from folder when user is offline.

Comment: but I need to get the location of the stored image to show image in another activity and I found that we can't get the path of cache image stored by picasso , so I followed this way to save images in external storage and use it. @sanat chandravanshi

Answer (score 0):

Operations like loading images should be performed using [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) on a background thread.

Comment: Can you please guide me with the code to load images from external storage from async task in recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

- Check every images how much **MB** it is.**For Example :** If the
  image is 1mb or 500kb it will take more time to download images in
  background and after downloaded it will store in catche.That means
  first time only it will take some time to download the image.
- on the second time, those images from catche.It will show all the
  images in the fraction of seconds.
- Use Volley - for faster and Glide - for Memory management.

  ```
  Glide
      .with(context)
      .load(rowItem.getPosteduserpostimage())
      .asBitmap()
      .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
      .fitCenter()
      .placeholder(R.drawable.load_image)
      .error(R.drawable.cancel_image)
      .into(holder.ivPostedImageNew);
  ```
- Refer
  [here](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)
  how to load large size bitmap.You need to scale down image.
- Otherwise, When I'm uploading every image, I did crop using
  library.It will take care of scale down large bitmap.**for eg:** 5mb
  images will be scale down to 180 kb.
- Check this [CropImage
  lib](https://github.com/biokys/cropimage/tree/master/simple-crop-image-lib)
  to scale down bigger size images.Even if user not crop image,just
  select the entire portion when cropping, it will scale down 5 mb to
  180kb.Image Quality also good.

I think without crop also you can use the below code to scale down image.You can see this code in that:

```
private void startCropImage() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CropImage.class);

    intent.putExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH, mFileTemp.getPath());
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.SCALE, true);
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_X, 0); //3 for aspect ratio
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_Y, 0); //2 for aspect ratio

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CROP_IMAGE);
}
```

- And also don't use nested scroll view inside recyclerview.